# increment a value each time the next row is different from the previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df :

```
name
str_a
str_a
str_a
str_b
str_b
str_c
str_c
```

In the column `name` I got different `str`, I want to create another column named `number` which has for the first row 0 then each time the previuous name is different from the next one, it adds +1 to the previous number. The expected result would be  :

```
name  number
str_a 0
str_a 0
str_a 0
str_b 1
str_b 1 
str_c 2 
str_c 2
```

Is there a way to do that without a loop ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `shift` with `cumsum` , notice you may can check `df['name'].factorize()[0]` , however, if the name repeat but not always continue in a row `factorize` will not work

```
df['name'].ne(df['name'].shift()).cumsum()-1
Out[10]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
Name: name, dtype: int32
```

Comment: strings in `name` appears more than one time so `factorize` doesn't get what I want but your other reponse is perfect !